# WPF DataGrid disable auto scroll

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Basically I have an application to help me sort/catalogue my collection of photos and movies. It's really simple, I have a `DataGrid` which has all the files in a specific folder listed in it. There are two columns: `Keep` and `Filename`. I would go down this DataGrid using arrows and press space whether I want to keep the file (the first column is `bool`, so when I press space, the checkbox is being checked). So without clicking anything it looks like this:

[image]

But when I click on the filename (when I click on the same row, but `Keep` column, it doesn't scroll, but it's so much smaller compared to filename column, so I end up always clicking the filename column part of the row) and it's too long it scrolls horizontally, like this:

[image]

The problem is that now I don't see the `Keep` column, so I have to manually scroll back, to see if I marked the file or not. So to solve this, I saw many answers on SO suggesting editing the XAML part of the `MainWindow`. The problem is, this is my XAML file:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="FileOrganiser.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FileOrganiser"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="File Organiser" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="8*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <MediaElement x:Name="Media" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="5"/>
        <DataGrid x:Name="FilesList" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  SelectionChanged="FilesList_OnSelectionChanged">
        </DataGrid>
        <Button x:Name="ButtonSOrt" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"></Button>
    </Grid>
</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

The important part is, that I don't define columns myself and this is how I fill up the datagrid:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    while (true)
    {
        RootDir = FileUtils.SelectRootFolder();
        if (RootDir == string.Empty) MessageBox.Show("Select a root folder!");
        else break;
    }
    files = Directory.GetFiles(RootDir);
    var videos = files.Select(file => new Video(Path.GetFileName(file), false)).ToList();
    FilesList.ItemsSource = videos;
}
```

So I do it by changing the `ItemSource` in code. And if I would define the columns myself and also change `ItemSource` like this, I would have 4 columns instead of 2. So is there a way to prevent this autoscroll, when I am implementing it this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decided to make this another answer as this should be the preferred way to go since it gives you a lot more control over your layout:

put this in your XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="FilesList" HorizontalAlignment="Center" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Keep}" Width="25"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Filename}" Width="*"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

there should be no changes needed in your code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Datagrid should have an attached property for this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.horizontalscrollbarvisibility?view=netframework-4.8

Set this to "Disabled":

```
Scrollviewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
```

Comment: Hiding the scrollbar doesn't change the fact that after a mouse click, it scrolls. The scrollbar is not present but it still does scroll

Comment: Ahh my bad. Of course you have to set it to disabled ;)

Comment: Another thing: You can also set the ```AutoGenerateColumns``` property of the DataGrid to false and then define the colums yourself without ending up with 4 columns in the end.